# How to Automate an email I

Tags: unix

I receive an email from a user with a Excel File Monday-Friday. I usually download the file and do a name change and save it as a CSV file and load it into the server.

Can I automate this process by any chance using Unix?

Thank you.

Comment: That really depends on how you receive and process mail, doesn't it? You don't happen to be familiar with `procmail`, do you? Indeed, until we know a lot more about your intent it is not clear that this is a programming question at all.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, it is *potentially* possible.

Longer answer: It depends. The approach and viability will depend on various factors:

- How are you receiving your email? Will you be able to run your script on the email server itself or do you need to retrieve the emails to your local machine?
- Are the target emails easily identifiable (specific sender/title/content)? Does it contain a link to the Excel file or is it included as an attachment?
- Can you assume a specific Excel format or do you need to consider arbitrary Excel versions?
- What do you mean by *"load it into the server"*? Do you need to copy it to a specific directory? Move it to a remote machine via FTP/SCP?
- Do you need to process the incoming emails as they come it, or can you process them periodically in batches?

That said, your question is unfortunately too open-ended for StackOverflow (see [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)). You should try implementing you solution first then post a question when you have *specific* difficulties or questions. It helps if you include details of the problem and what you've tried so far.

To help you move forward, here are some pointers:

- If your email is store remotely, use something like [fetchmail](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/mail-fetchmail.html) to fetch emails via POP/IMAP to your local mailbox
- To automate the call to fetchmail, you can [schedule it using cron](http://www.scalix.com/wiki/index.php?title=HowTos/Fetchmail#Automating_Fetchmail).
- Once the email arrives in your local mailbox, you can use [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) to filter out specific emails and pass its content to an arbitrary command/script for processing
- You can use [munpack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/munpack) to extract attachments from an email
- If you need help with any of the above tools, there are lots of relevant resources indexed by google. You could also ask on [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munpack+or+fetchmail+or+procmail) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/munpack+or+fetchmail+or+procmail).
- To convert an Excel file to CSV, you can look into [xls2csv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xls2csv). If you cannot install the command using your distro's package manager, the source is distributed along with [catdoc](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/)

I'm afraid I cannot design a full solution for you, but I hope this will at least give you a starting point. Good luck.